# How to prevent some methods

Tags: api, laravel-5.5

I'm developing some APIs with Laravel 5.5

The methods I am using are only 'GET'/'POST'/'PUT'/'PATCH'/'DELETE'.

All works fine except if the request is HEAD or LOCK (for example) ....

In this case, the backend returns a 405 error with an html response. And in this html response there are a lot confidential data.

Is it possible , only for some methods, that the back returns a single text "Method not allowed" and not an html file ? Is it a good practice to do that or not necessary?

I imagine a middleware, but which one?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting debug information with confidential data is likely due to `debug` being set to `true` in your config. If you turn this to `false`, the error message will remove the confidential data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

File **Exceptions/handler.php**, method **render**, I had this:

```
if ($request->is('api/*') and ! in_array($request->method(), ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete']) ){
    return response()->json("request not allowed", 405);
}
```

It works fine. Now I receive a JSON response instead of an HTML response for all my API routes, depending on 'get/put/post/delete'.